# How to send a square matrix through sockets in udp?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I'm using python 2.7 and i have to send a square matrix between two hosts using socket programming in udp. My code sends a string but not a matrix.

This is my code:

```
import socket
import thread
import time
import ctypes
matrix = [[1,2],[3,5]]
def c():
  #print (file.read())
  UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
  UDP_PORT = 5002
  #MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"
  print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
  print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
  #print ("message:", MESSAGE)
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                       socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
  sock.sendto(matrix, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

def s():  
  UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
  UDP_PORT = 5002
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                       socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
  sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))  
  while True:
       data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
       print "received message:", data
while True:
      thread.start_new_thread(c, ())
      thread.start_new_thread(s, ())
      time.sleep(10)
```

Also, I found this code online. It sends a matrix but i am unable deserialize it according to my needs (in matrix form as the input). If anyone can help me understand this that would be of much help.

Server end:

```
import socket, pickle
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(4096)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

Client end

```
import socket, pickle

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
arr = [[11111],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
data_string = pickle.dumps(arr)
s.send(data_string)

data = s.recv(4096)
data_arr = pickle.loads(data)

s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data_arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should read from the same port, as you send data. Data has to be send as binary. You can use `pickle` as in your second example. Don't start server threads over and over again.

```
import socket
import time
import pickle
import threading

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5002

def server():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))  
    while True:
         data, addr = sock.recvfrom(102400)
         matrix = pickle.loads(data)
         print "received message:", matrix

def send_matrix(matrix):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    data = pickle.dumps(matrix)
    sock.sendto(data, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

threading.Thread(target=server).start()
matrix = [[1,2],[3,5]]
while True:
    send_matrix(matrix)
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Actually i was using two programs to communicate with each other. Ones port no os 5001 and the other is 5002. Data has to be send again and again for bellman ford algorithm to cater any changes. thats why i used time delay in threading.

Comment: _Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 483, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\6\linda.py", line 11, in server
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, 5002))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 222, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted_

Comment: I tried your code edited it with port nos 5001 and 5002 for two programs but im getting these errors .